# How to use $lookup if the localField is an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i have a user schema and a post schema  ..the user schema has an array field 'posts' which references the post schema, and in the user schema contains an array field  'followings' references the user schema ..
This is the User Schema

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    //required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    //required: true
  },
  dob: {
    type: Date,
    //required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    //required: true
  },
  posts :[
  {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Post'}
],
  password: {
    type: String,
   // required: true
  },
  
  followers: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref:'User'
  }],
  following:  [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref:'User'
  }]
    
});
```

and the post schema

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    body: {
        type: String
    },
    topic: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Topics'
    },
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    createdBy:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
    
    },
     createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
     },
     comments:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref:'Comment' 
     }],
     updatedAt:{
         type: Date,
         default: Date.now()
     }
});
```

i am getting stuck on how to query mongoose for all posts of users that he is following
how do i query for all post user followings , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the aggregate function.

1. filter the result for the user using $match.
2. $unwind the "following" field (since local field can't be an array in the next stage).
3. find the posts using $lookup
4. clean up your output using $project.

the solution should be something like this(not tested):

```
db.users.aggregate([
   {
      "$match":{
         "username":"user_username"
      }
   },
   {
      "$unwind":"$following"
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"posts",
         "localField":"following",
         "foreignField":"createdBy",
         "as":"posts"
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "posts":1,
         "following":1,
         "_id":0
      }
   }
])
```